# Google Colab error - wrong CuDNN library version being loaded?

Tags: keras, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I've been running Keras on Google Colab, and for the last day or so I'm getting the below error when I use the GPU. It works fine when using TPU acceleration.

Looking at the logs, I see this error. It looks to me like CoLab is not loading the right version of a library - but I don't think I have any control over that process. What do I do?

Thanks!!

> May 9, 2019, 9:21:08 PM   WARNING 2019-05-09 14:21:08.027926: E
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:324]  Loaded runtime CuDNN
>   library: 7.3.1 but source was compiled with: 7.4.2. CuDNN library
>   major and minor version needs to match or have higher minor version in
>   case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version.  If using a binary install,
>   upgrade your CuDNN library. If building from sources, make sure the
>   library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified
>   during compile configuration.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-fc8da73d140a> in <module>()
     19     [x_train, x_train_pos_enc], y_train, validation_split=0.2,
     20     batch_size=batch_size,
---> 21     epochs=10, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=1)
     22 endtime = time.time()
     23 print(f'This took {endtime-starttime:.2f} seconds')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    878           initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    879           steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
--> 880           validation_steps=validation_steps)
    881 
    882   def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, mode, validation_in_fit, **kwargs)
    327 
    328         # Get outputs.
--> 329         batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    330         if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    331           batch_outs = [batch_outs]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3074 
   3075     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3076                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3077     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3078     return nest.pack_sequence_as(self._outputs_structure,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
   1440         if run_metadata:
   1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv1d/conv1d/Conv2D}}]]
     [[{{node loss/dense_1_loss/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/is_valid_shape/has_valid_nonscalar_shape/has_invalid_dims/concat}}]]
```

Comment: Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Hi Bob, actually the problem just... disappeared when I re-ran the notebook a few hours after I posted this. I am not sure what to make of it actually.

Comment: Sometimes this error occurs due to the GPU running out of memory. (Confusing to be sure, but c'est la vie.) A common work-around is to reduce batch size or to halt other notebooks running in the background that may also have reserved GPU memory. (Use the Runtime -> Manage sessions... menu.)

Comment: @Bob Smith - If it is a memory related problem, this error message is very misleading.  If it is a memory related problem, it should state as it is.  The message clearly states that there is a mismatch between compilation version and runtime version.